# Get object in a Set that is an instance of a generically specified type

Tags: java, generics, set

Are there ways to simplify the `getLoadComponent(Class<T> type)` method? The call `LoadComponentFX lcfx = l.getLoadComponent(LoadComponentFX.class);` seams a bit clumsy to me.

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class LoadComponent {}

public class LoadComponentFX extends LoadComponent {}

public class Load {
    Set<LoadComponent> lc;

    public <T extends LoadComponent> T getLoadComponent(Class<T> type) {
        for (final LoadComponent l : lc) {
            if (type.isInstance(l)) {
                return (T) l;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
public class LoadTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Load l = new PointLoad();

        LoadComponentFX lcfx = l.getLoadComponent(LoadComponentFX.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your current code now indirectly forces the set to only contain one of each component, then you could use a `Map` instead. This would also reduce the need for the loop

```
public class Load {
    Map<Class<? extends LoadComponent>, LoadComponent> lc;

    public <T extends LoadComponent> T getLoadComponent(Class<T> type) {
        return (T) lc.get(type);
    }
}
```

Other comments:

- Make sure the `Map` is set to `private final`
- `lc` is not a good name. There's really no need to save bytes by shortening variable names. A better name would be `loadComponents`
- When adding items to the map, you can use `loadComponents.put(obj.getClass(), obj);`